# What's with the creepy text?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I've noticed now when I defeat enemies, every now and again I will get text in light grey font that is kinda creepy.

The last one I saw said "your life is the blink of an eye."

What's going on with the creepy text?

Comment: dunno couldn't find this string in the source code, maybe it's new

Comment: Might be something about a halloween event that is coming up? I'm just guessing though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the effect of the [Telltale™ rubber heart](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Telltale%E2%84%A2_rubber_heart), a social item that can be found by owners of the [Hauntd doghouse](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Haunted_doghouse) IotM. It can be used on other players, and it seems to last longer than a day.

Comment: Okay, I don't have that IotM, but someone else used it on me, and that's why I am getting the text?

Comment: Yup. These "creepy" items are *social items*, like toilet paper, bricks, jawbruisers etc: intended to be used on other people to annoy or entertain them.